# A how + adjective question

Tags: syntax, questions, sentence

Does anyone know how to setup a question that uses "how + adjective." Like in this context:

> Do you know how loud you were?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use どのぐらい・どれぐらい・どれだけ + adj.

> **どれだけ**うるさかったか気づいてる？　→　Do you know how loud you were?

There is also どんなに, but my feeling is that this is a little more formal.